# Digit Product Inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

On the OEIS (https://oeis.org/A007954) I found the following inequality:

> For the digit product $a(n)$ of the number $n$, which is simply the product of it's digits, we have
> $$
> a(n)\leq 9^{1+\log_{10}(\frac{n}{9})}.
> $$

For the digit sum we have
$$
s(n)\leq 9(1+\lfloor \log_{10}n\rfloor)
$$
where $1+\lfloor \log_{10}n\rfloor$ is a bound for the amount of digits of a number. Therefore, the upper bound
$$
K(n)\leq 9^{1+\lfloor \log_{10}n\rfloor}
$$
is easily derived. Intuitively, the product is bounded by a product of $9$'s, as $9$ is the highest digit.

Has anyone an idea for deriving the bound from OEIS?

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point.  The number of digits in $n$ is $F(n)=\lfloor \log_{10}n\rfloor +1$, right?  And you can't have higher digital product then if all the digits are $9$, so we have the obvious upper bound $a(n)≤9^{\lfloor \log_{10}n\rfloor +1}$.  Is that good enough?

Comment: @lulu No, look we have log(n/9) not log n.

Comment: I understand, but the bound I gave is often stronger.

Comment: The bound you gave is obvious, I want to understand how this was derived.

Comment: Well, I suggest adapting the one you think is obvious.  The two are extremely close...(they never differ by as much as $1$).

Comment: I do not see the merit to avoid the floor-function and instead to use a less accurate expression. The bound given by lulu is more sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition for this inequality is that $\frac{n}{9}$ has either the same number of digits as $n$ or one less. Intuitively, this makes sense because $\frac{n}{10}$ has exactly one less digit than $n$ and $\frac{n}{10}\leq\frac{n}{9}\leq n$.

More formally, we can show this because $\log_{10}(\frac{n}{9})=\log_{10}(n)-\log_{10}(9)$ and $0<\log_{10}(9)<1$.

The number of digits in $n$ is $1+\lfloor\log_{10}(n)\rfloor$ and likewise the number of digits in $\frac{n}{9}$ is $1+\lfloor\log_{10}(\frac{n}{9})\rfloor$.

Since $\frac{n}{9}$ has the same number of digits as $n$ or one less, we have that $2+\lfloor\log_{10}(n)\rfloor\leq1+\lfloor\log_{10}(\frac{n}{9})\rfloor$.

So, $1+\lfloor\log_{10}(n)\rfloor\leq\lfloor\log_{10}(\frac{n}{9})\rfloor$.

Note that $\lfloor x\rfloor\leq 1+x$, so $\lfloor\log_{10}(\frac{n}{9})\rfloor\leq1+\log_{10}(\frac{n}{9})$.

So, by your "obvious" equation: $a(n)\leq9^{1+\lfloor\log_{10}(n)\rfloor}\leq9^{\lfloor\log_{10}(\frac{n}{9})\rfloor}\leq9^{1+\log_{10}(\frac{n}{9})}$ and we are done.

Comment: For small values, $f$ (OEIS bound) gives better values than the obvious one $g$. E.g. $f(123)\approx 109.13$, $g(123)=729.$